# Can't Create Role Assignment in Pipeline with Owner Service Principle

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, service-principal

I have a build pipeline which deploys some ARM templates. It's a requirement for some of those resources to have role assignments for RBAC.

The service principle that the pipeline uses to connect to subscription is an owner, but if either the templates try to create role assignment resources, or I try to run az cli in the pipeline to create the assignments, there's insufficient permissions.

What permissions above owner is required to allow this?

Comment: The service principle that your signed in may no have the permission, You can check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5738), You can also try to login as a user who is a global admin to perform assignment

Comment: Nope. The service principal is an owner of the subscription - a global admin.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you misunderstood the `Global admin` and `Owner`. The `Global admin` is an [`Administrator role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) in Azure AD, and the `Owner` is an [`RBAC role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) in the subscription. They are different things.

When you use the azure cli like below to create the role assignment, it adds the service principal `joytestsp` as an `Owner` to the storage account. The service principal which you login needs to call the AAD Graph to get the object first and then call the azure mangement rest api to add it to the storage account.

```
az role assignment create --assignee 'joytestsp' --role 'Owner' --scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joyfunction'
```

So to fix the issue, you could navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> click the `Global administrator` -> `Add assignments`-> add your service principal which used to login as a `Global administrator`. Then it should work.

---

**Besides**, if you don't want to give it the `Global administrator` to the service principal, you can also specify the `object id` of the service principal/user in the command, then it will also work.

```
az role assignment create --assignee 'b4d3c922-xxxxxxx-3ab785333011' --role 'Owner' --scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joyfunction'
```